# Are there any bodies or agencies that collate UK polling data?

Tags: democracy, united-kingdom, public-opinion, data-sources

I used to use [UK Polling Report](http://www.ukpollingreport.co.uk) but recently their updates have become more infrequent and I'm not sure how much I trust the analysis or selection of data. Are there any other sources from which I could find a roundup of polling done in the UK? All of it if possible (I know that might not be feasible, though).

I would be particularly interested in any websites, organisations etc which would provide not only the data itself, but also provide a breakdown of collection methodologies and perhaps even contact details for anyone involved in creating and collating the studies.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what kinds of polls are you looking for? Are you interested mostly in opinion polls, or are you looking for social surveys, etc.?

Comment: In collation of data (not to be confused with collection of data, which is a very similar word, but missing one of the connotations I wished to retain) regarding democracy polling data. That is, of polling related to elections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sympathetic, having often turned to the UK Polling Report (UKPR) for some insight into the current 'mood'.

By definition, a poll of polls is a collection of snapshots of the prevailing mood and always be on a single issue, such as a particular election or referendum. After the event, there is no reason to collect polling data and, so, UKPR will not have the information from which it feeds.

The methodology should be available from the site of the polling company, and The British Polling Council (BPC)  ( http://www.britishpollingcouncil.org/ ) provides a list of its members and, importantly, as its current President, Prof John Curtice, stated just before the 2015 UK General Election:

> BPC members will be making full details of their published polls
>   available as quickly as possible throughout the election campaign so
>   that everyone can come to their own view as to whether they believe
>   the results are robust and reliable or not. But inevitably members can
>   only do so for those polls for which they are themselves responsible.
>   If someone claims their poll was conducted by a BPC member, do please
>   check the claim out. It may not be true.
>   http://www.britishpollingcouncil.org/category/blog/

The data for public polling should also be available though I find this to be hit and miss, probably because it belongs to the company.